# How to put benchmark line on barchart?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

We are using the jfreechart with Jasper reports and we are struggling to put the benchmark line on the bar chart.

[image: We need to add the redline on bar]

How can this be achieved using jasper reports?

Comment: Hi Santosh, can you post code sample of what you have tried so far? that will make it easier for others to correct/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize your bar chart in jasper report create a customizer class (ChartCustomizer) extending the [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractChartCustomizer.html).

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ChartComponent chartComponent)
{
  //get the ploy
  CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

  //Now add your markers
  ValueMarker vm = new ValueMarker(200); //200 is the position you like it to be
  vm.setPaint(Color.RED);
  vm.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
  vm.setLabel("BeanchMark value"); //The label
  vm.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP);
  vm.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
  plot.addRangeMarker(vm);
}
```

add the class to classpath and in jrxml set the `customizerClass` attribute

```
<barChart>
    <chart customizerClass="my.package.ChartCustomizer">
   ....
    </chart>
   ...
</barChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved it by using the following code in customise class

```
ValueMarker marker = new ValueMarker(30);
    marker.setLabel("Average 30%");
    marker.setPaint(Color.black);
    plot.addRangeMarker(marker);
```

However we need to change the label position, currently it is showing at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

For one single horizontal line you can use provided chart customizer:

Go to Chart -> Properties -> Chart (tab) -> Chart customizers

[image: Chart properties]

There you can add a Range Interval Marker and configure it with start and end values with the desired value (35 in your example).

This way an horizontal line will be drawn in the 35 vertical value as you wanted.