# How to position legend chart labels?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

Is it possible to change the default positions of the legend labels around the jasper reports charts? Currently I have a following kind of chart being created:

[image]

I would like to move this [hoursNormal, hoursTravel, hoursOvertime]-box from under the chart to the right side of the chart. Another thing I would like to do is to replace this [hoursNormal, hoursTravel, hoursOvertime]-box by label "month". I just don't see any tools for moving these positions in Jasper studio chart creation wizard, and to me also the xml looks like so static that I don't believe tinkering it would help me.

Hopefully I'm wrong and there is a easy solution?

Comment: Nice screen shot, you have attribution for that, just kidding : )

Comment: The "replace this [hoursNormal, hoursTravel, hoursOvertime]-box by label "month" is not clear what you mean (invert series and categories?), but I have answered so you can see how to set all properties on chart.

Comment: By this "replace this [hoursNormal, hoursTravel, hoursOvertime]-box by label "month" I was meaning that I would just like to print localized text "Month" under the chart. Basically your answer pointed me to the right direction with this one as well, as I noticed that it's possible to define the title for the report from the basic chart properties and position it to bottom. Yeah, that's one hell of a screenshot and I have a feeling I'm about to use it in one more question:)

Comment: here's one more follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868214/jasper-reports-multitype-chart-is-it-possible-to-add-xy-line-to-bar-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the legend to the right and other option of the chart can be find in the **Properties** View.

Click the chart, to view Properties for the chart. Navigate the different properties tabs to set what you need.

**Example**

[image: Screen shot]

If you need more advanced feature on the chart you need to use a customizer class see this as example: [How to put benchmark line on barchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649022/how-to-put-benchmark-line-on-barchart/35649403#35649403)

Comment: Oh, that was easy, no wonder no one had asked this before here:) Thanks!

Comment: JasperReport Studio is fairly new.... and I had a chance to do some free hand circles : )